# Android XML values - String Array :: Placing a quote in the value?

Tags: android, xml, arrays

I have a string array in strings.xml, in the values I need to have shutter speeds.

For example:

> 3"2

or

> 0"8

I try to  enter the data in the xml, but that does not work. Alternatively; when I enter the value in the graphical interface of the strings.xml file, it places the data as
[image: screen dump]

Which does not display when I place the array in a spinner later on.

Basically, I would like to know how to display a single quotation mark in a string of a string array and have it display in a spinner later on.

Thanks for any help, have a nice day.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try:

```
3\"2
```

and

```
0\"8
```

Check out [String Resources > Formatting and Styling](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#FormattingAndStyling) on the official docs.

Comment: Thank you heaps. Can't believe there was doco on that, I searched for ages.